# Running Terminal Command in Android App to Route Audio

Tags: android, apk, su, root, audio-route

So i have an LG P920 I want to Modify The T.I FMrX app to add commands to route audio via tinymix here are the shell commands

> ```
> # tinymix 6 120
> # tinymix 66 7
> # tinymix 67 7
> # tinymix 73 2
> # tinymix 74 2
> ```

binary is located at `/system/bin/tinymix`

so am trying to impliment it in java im not sure its correct but here its is

```
 public static void RouteAudioOn()
    {
    String MIX = "tinymix";
    int DL1 = 6;
    int DL1Value = 120;
    int FMvol = 66;
    int Headsetvol = 67'
    int RightCh = 73;
    int LeftCh = 74;
    int SoundValue  = 7;
    int HeadsetValue = 8;
    int LineIn = 2

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+DL1+" "+DL1Value"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+FMvol+" "+SoundValue"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+Headsetvol+" "+HeadsetValue"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+RightCh+" "+LineIn"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+LeftCh+" "+LineIn"\n");

    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    process.waitFor();
    }  

 public static void RouteAudioOff()
    {
    String MIX = "tinymix";
    int DL1 = 6;
    int DL1Value = 0;
    int FMvol = 66;
    int Headsetvol = 67'
    int RightCh = 73;
    int LeftCh = 74;
    int SoundValue  = 0;
    int HeadsetValue = 0;
    int LineIn = 0

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());

    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+DL1+" "+DL1Value"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+FMvol+" "+SoundValue"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+Headsetvol+" "+HeadsetValue"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+RightCh+" "+LineIn"\n");
    os.writeBytes(MIX+" "+LeftCh+" "+LineIn"\n");

    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
    os.close();

    process.waitFor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i made it like this and is ok

boolean son=false for headset and true for handsfree

```
public void RunAsRoot(boolean son) {
    Process p = null;
    ArrayList tmpCmd = new ArrayList();
    tmpCmd.add("chmod 777 /dev/radio0");
    tmpCmd.add("tinymix 6 120");
    tmpCmd.add("tinymix 66 4");
if(son){tmpCmd.add("tinymix 67 1");tmpCmd.add("tinymix 73 1");
tmpCmd.add("tinymix 74 0");tmpCmd.add("tinymix 68 28");tmpCmd.add("tinymix 75 2");tmpCmd.add("tinymix 76 2");}
else    {tmpCmd.add("tinymix 75 0");tmpCmd.add("tinymix 76 0");tmpCmd.add("tinymix 68 0");tmpCmd.add("tinymix 67 4");
tmpCmd.add("tinymix 73 2");
tmpCmd.add("tinymix 74 2");}

    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());            
    for (int i=0;i<tmpCmd.size();i++) {
       try {
        os.writeBytes(tmpCmd.get(i)+"\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }           
    try {
         os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    try {
        os.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```